# tips to improve gmapping results

Tags: ros, navigation, pioneer, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings,

I am running slam_gmapping ( gmapping ) in PioneerAT with Sick LMS200 on ROS Diamondback.
I am using slam_gmapping_pr2.launch from gmapping package. Following picture shows the result. TF defined is also visible in image.

The map is curved on straight corridors. Parallel corridors are merged. A small circular move (loop ~ radius 3meters, at center) is not detected. One corridor has come twice (parallel,joined) due to some problem.

I tried changing the launch file and used following:

```
<launch>
    <param name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" output="screen">
<!--      <remap from="scan" to="scan"/>-->
    <param name="odom_frame" value="/RosAria/pose"/>
      <param name="map_udpate_interval" value="2.0"/>
      <param name="maxUrange" value="12.0"/>
      <param name="sigma" value="0.05"/>
      <param name="kernelSize" value="1"/>
      <param name="lstep" value="0.05"/>
      <param name="astep" value="0.05"/>
      <param name="iterations" value="5"/>
      <param name="lsigma" value="0.075"/>
      <param name="ogain" value="3.0"/>
      <param name="lskip" value="0"/>
      <param name="srr" value="0.1"/>
      <param name="srt" value="0.2"/>
      <param name="str" value="0.1"/>
      <param name="stt" value="0.2"/>
      <param name="linearUpdate" value="0.5"/>
      <param name="angularUpdate" value="0.5"/>
      <param name="temporalUpdate" value="3.0"/>
      <param name="resampleThreshold" value="0.5"/>
      <param name="particles" value="30"/>
      <param name="xmin" value="-50.0"/>
      <param name="ymin" value="-50.0"/>
      <param name="xmax" value="50.0"/>
      <param name="ymax" value="50.0"/>
      <param name="delta" value="0.05"/>
      <param name="llsamplerange" value="0.01"/>
      <param name="llsamplestep" value="0.01"/>
      <param name="lasamplerange" value="0.005"/>
      <param name="lasamplestep" value="0.005"/>
    </node>
</launch>
```

This resulted in even worse map shown in picture below:

```
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-90.753
lp:18.5471 -20.6458 -1.92343
op:18.1182 -5.70109 1.08139
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-297.351
lp:18.5471 -20.6458 -1.92343
op:18.1182 -5.70109 1.08139
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-822.941
lp:18.5471 -20.6458 -1.92343
op:18.1182 -5.70109 1.08139
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-1200
lp:18.5471 -20.6458 -1.92343
op:18.1182 -5.70109 1.08139
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-1200
lp:18.5471 -20.6458 -1.92343
op:18.1182 -5.70109 1.08139
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-987.667
lp:18.5471 -20.6458 -1.92343
op:18.1182 -5.70109 1.08139
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-1200
lp:18.5471 -20.6458 -1.92343
op:18.1182 -5.70109 1.08139
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-257.575
lp:18.5471 -20.6458 -1.92343
op:18.1182 -5.70109 1.08139
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-1200
lp:18.5471 -20.6458 -1.92343
op:18.1182 -5.70109 1.08139
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-216.73
lp:18.5471 -20.6458 -1.92343
op:18.1182 -5.70109 1.08139
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-1008.48
lp:18.5471 -20.6458 -1.92343
op:18.1182 -5.70109 1.08139
```

Above are some of console output which may be of help in diagonising the problem.

**The bag** file can be found here:  http://www.mediafire.com/?4ftzaenx28ilfow

I am not able to make out what wrong I am doing?

Is there any checklist page which help on checking out potential configuration issues?

It fares really badly on in place rotations. in-place-rotations are not so fast. What can be done to improve that.

Why straight corridors are coming curved? any ideas?

Any help page or help link for similar problem? I tried searching forum but nothing much could be found.

Laser mounted on pioneer, looks down. It is not parallel to ground. Could it be a problem?

thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31036/tips-to-improve-gmapping-results/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2012-04-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I recall correctly, gmapping doesn't support mapping with a tilted laser scanner. It should be perpendicular to the ground or otherwise not see something like ground or ceiling every scan, otherwise the scan matching will not work properly.

If you really want to keep your laser tilted, you'll need to do something to filter the ground plane out of the scans.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From my experience, changing the linearUpdate parameter and the angularUpdate parameter to a lower value while increasing the number of particles (100 is the usual amount for me) provides better performance [as long as your computer can process it].

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-04-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-04-02**:
i was expecting it to run online. Will this not overload the machine? I do not know why scan matching is failed, which as per paper is critical for Rao Blackewellised PF s.